# How to batch multiple transactions into one single GRPC call in Hyperledger Fabric SDK?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I believe for each and every transaction sent a separate GRPC connection is established by Fabric SDK client while sending transactions for endorsement. I am looking for batching API to send independent transactions in a single GRPC call(Like 100 tx per batch), NodeJS SDK documentation doesn't reflect any such APIs.

Comment: Can you provide some detail in your question about how you are using the node sdk and coming to this conclusion. I could guess how you might think this is happening and it could be around how you are using the node sdk

Comment: Coming from Ethereum background, the SDK web3.js provides an API called web3.batchTransactions([transactions]). All these transactions are sent over single HTTP RPC call instead N number of RPC calls. I am looking for such APIs in Hyperledger NodeJS SDK